# Foreign Key to All Objects? Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I've tried finding documentation on this, but I can't seem to get anything close to what I'm trying to do.

I want to create a model for a checklist which has easily updateable checklist items. I want to have our HR person be able to easily add checklist items via the admin panel and have them automatically attached to each and every NewHireChecklist.

Here's where I'm at:

```
class NewHireChecklist(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
         return 'Checklist - %s %s' % (self.employee.fName, self.employee.lName)

class NewHireChecklistItem(models.Model):
    checklist = models.ForeignKey(NewHireChecklist)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

However, I want the checklist to automatically apply to every single NewHireChecklist object, not just the ones that I specifically specify.

Any thoughts on proceeding? Am I thinking about this in the completely wrong way?

Thanks!

Comment: So you want `checklist` to have multiple `NewHireCheckList`s in it? because i believe thats a many to many relationship instead of foreign key.. but it actually sounds like you want a many to many object called "items" under `NewHireCheckList` instead, choosing the `NewHireChecklistItem` as the key

Comment: Not quite. I want every NewHireChecklist to have a predefined set of NewHireChecklistItems which can be added to via the admin panel.

Comment: ManyToMany is the Multiple version of Foreign Key

Comment: That's fine. I can change that in the model, but my real concern is having the pre-loaded list. So, when I create the ChecklistItems, every Checklist created after that will automatically be tied to each ChecklistItem.

Comment: so your goal is to create a few NewHireCheckListItem, lets say "Monitor" and "Battle Axe" and "Deoderant"... then create a new model called "Presets" and creat a few  objects: "warrior" and "programmer" (warrior = battle axe + deoderant, and programmer = monitor and "deoderant )... this Presets model would have to have a ManyToMany relationship with newhirechecklistItems...right?... then after all of this, when on the admin page for NewHireChecklist, someone would just click the dropdown and select "warrior" and they would be assigned a battle axe and deoderant

Comment: Not quite. Every time a NewHireChecklist is created, I want all of the NewHireChecklistItems attached to it automatically. I don't want the user to have to actually select the items that are attached to the Checklist. I want every checklist to automatically be attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want a one to many field but a many to many. You want several checklists to have the same items and several items in the same checklist.

Just create a many to many and override the save() on your model to add all the existing check list items.

Comment: That's the ticket. It's the overridden save() method that I was looking for. Thanks!